# SQL Server Profiler 2005 on remote SQL Server 2008 Express?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, profiler

Is it possible to trace remote SQL Server 2008 using SQL Profiler 2005? If yes, does anyone know what else should I do, if during logging in I get the message

> Unable to locate trace definition file for SQL Server version 10.0.0"

I read [Unable to read trace definition file Microsoft SQL Server TraceDefinition n.n1.n2.xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlserverfaq/unable-to-read-trace-definition-file-microsoft-sql-server-tracedefinition-n-n1-n2-xml), but my SQLPath registry key looks good. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those messages about 'unable to read trace definition' and the fix are always from a newer SQL Profiler version trying to connect to an older SQL Server version. You are trying the other way (from older SQL Profiler to newer SQL Server) and it won't work. AFAIK You need to use SQL Profiler 2008 or newer.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the profiler, try to run a server-side trace.

You can start here: http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/w/wiki/10400.the-server-side-trace-what-why-and-how.aspx

Or you can just use the profiler to script out the trace creation.